# JavaScript - Filter <key,value> Object by key

Tags: javascript

I am looking for a short and efficient way to filter  objects by key, I have this kind of data-structure:

```
{"Key1":[obj1,obj2,obj3], "Key2":[obj4,obj5,obj6]}
```

Now I want to filter by keys, for example by `"Key1"`:

```
{"Key1":[obj1,obj2,obj3]}
```

Comment: If you have `var myObject = {"Key1":[obj1,obj2,obj3], "Key2":[obj4,obj5,obj6]};` shouldn't it just be `myObject['Key1']`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the `.filter` js function for filter values inside an object

```
var keys = {"Key1":[obj1,obj2,obj3], "Key2":[obj4,obj5,obj6]};

var objectToFind;

var keyToSearch = keys.filter(function(objects) {
  return objects === objectToFind
});
```

The `keyToSearch` is an array with all the objects filter by the `objectToFind` variable.

Remember, in the line `return objects === objectToFind` is where you have to should your statement. I hope it can help you.

Answer (score 2):

```js
var object = {"Key1":[1,2,3], "Key2":[4,5,6]};
var key1 = object["Key1"];
console.log(key1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new object based on some custom filter criteria by using a combination of `Object.keys` and the array `.reduce` method. Note this only works in es6:

```js
var myObject = {"Key1":["a","b","c"], "Key2":["e","f","g"]}

function filterObjectByKey(obj, filterFunc) {
    return Object.keys(obj).reduce((newObj, key) => {
        if (filterFunc(key)) {
            newObj[key] = obj[key];
        }
        
        return newObj;
    }, {});
}

const filteredObj = filterObjectByKey(myObject, x => x === "Key1")
console.log(filteredObj)
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what exactly are you trying to achieve, but if you want to have a set of keys that you would like to get the data for, you have quite a few options, one is:

```
var keys = ['alpha', 'bravo'];
var objectToFilterOn = {
  alpha: 'a',
  bravo: 'b',
  charlie: 'c'
};

keys.forEach(function(key) {
  console.log(objectToFilterOn[key]);
});
```